# Latex Multirow table background color: half displayed

Tags: latex

I am writing an essay in Latex and struggling with background color of a multi row table.

Here is the image. As you can se the last column on the right is only half coloured. I need its fully coloured.

[image]

Here is the corresponding extract of my code:

```
\rowcolor{RedFill}
5.88\% &10.6\% & 6.74\%  & \multirow{ 2}{*}{ALTA}\\
\rowcolor{RedFill}
9.01\% &14.6\% & 6.09\% \\
```

I also tried to apply different solutions suggested in Stackoverflow but it did not work for me (I am conscious that, by adapting the solution to my case, I am probabily applying it in the wrong way)

```
\rowcolor{RedFill}
5.88\% &10.6\% & 6.74\%  & \multirow{ 2}{*}{ALTA}\\
\rowcolor{RedFill}
9.01\% &14.6\% & 6.09\% & \rowcolor{RedFill}\\
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the `\multirow` statement in the lower row, and use a negative number for the row span:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\colorlet{RedFill}{red!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 5.88\% & 10.6\% & 6.74\% & \multirow{ 2}{*}{ALTA} \\
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 9.01\% & 14.6\% & 6.09\%
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 5.88\% & 10.6\% & 6.74\% & \multirow{ 2}{*}{ALTA} \\
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 9.01\% & 14.6\% & 6.09\% &
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 5.88\% & 10.6\% & 6.74\% & \\
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 9.01\% & 14.6\% & 6.09\% & \multirow{-2}{*}{ALTA}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 5.88\% & 10.6\% & 6.74\% & \\
  \rowcolor{RedFill} 9.01\% & 14.6\% & 6.09\% & \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{ALTA}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A similar option is provided by moving the content up using `\raisebox` (together with removing the resulting box height/depth - `[0pt][0pt]`).

Comment: YOU ARE MY SUPERHERO!!!! Thanks for helping my friend. It work brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\cellcolor`:

```
\rowcolor{RedFill} 5.88\% & 10.6\% & 6.74\% & \\
\rowcolor{RedFill} 9.01\% & 14.6\% & 6.09\% & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{RedFill} ALTA} \\
```

From https://texblog.org/2014/05/19/coloring-multi-row-tables-in-latex/

Comment: It run smoothly but it leaves the ultimo cell half coloured

Comment: Just edited the answer, adding an extra `&` at the end of the short row (if not, it does not exists and is not filled), and putting the `multirow` in the last row with a `-2` span (so background does not hides text).